# Finding root of $x^{16}-1 \equiv 0 \pmod {487}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find root of $x^{16}-1 \equiv 0 \pmod {487}$.
My approach is factorizing to get:

$$(x^8+1)(x^4+1)(x^2+1)(x-1)(x+1) \equiv 0 \pmod {487}$$

so I can confirm $1$ and $486$ are roots but there can be at most $16$ roots, how can I find the rest?

Comment: One of the brackets needs to be $(x-1)$?

Comment: yes, thanks for telling me

Comment: Since $487 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ and it is a prime number, there are no other solutions.

Comment: thanks. i wonder why do we need to consider mod 4 here.

Comment: @Alana Sometimes $4k+1$ or $4k+3$ primes (or just integers in general) have particular properties that can be useful in general throughout Number Theory, including here.

Comment: We cannot tell you all the story if you don't tell us what you know (or what you are supposed to know) to solve this exercize. What happens is that for primes $p$, $-1$ is a square $\pmod{p}$ if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. To see this, pick a generator of the multiplicative group of $\Bbb{Z}/p \Bbb{Z}$, and see what happens. For a reference, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Prime_modulus

Answer (score 4):

$487$ is a prime of the form $4k+3$, so $-1$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $487$. Hence, there cannot be further solutions. Otherwise , one of the equations $x^8\equiv -1\mod 487$ , $x^4\equiv -1\mod 487$  , $x^2\equiv -1\mod 487$ would be solveable, and this is impossible.

Comment: Thanks. So if one of them has the quadratic residue 3, e.g. $x^2 \equiv 3$ modulo 487, would there be a root here?

Comment: We can only be sure that a factor of the form $x^2+c$ has roots (if $-c$ is a quadratic residue). For $x^k+c$ with $k>2$, we need other methods to decide whether it has roots.